# Prevent loading of functions

Tags: functions

I use a theme, that includes sharing functions of a service called "Sharethis" and Font-Awesome. As far as I can see the functions are loaded from the following lines in the functions.php.

TT_ENQUEUE::add_css(array('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'));
TT_ENQUEUE::add_js(array('https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js'));

How can I use a child function (since the changes in the parent would be gone after an update) to:

completely disable the sharethis-feature
tell the theme to load font-awesome from the local server?

Any help is appreciated :)

Greetings
Markus

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume `add_css` and `add_js` are wrappers for `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script`.

As such, the way you register any style / script is through either `wp_dequeue_style` and `wp_dequeue_script`, **where you pass the handle of the scripts.**

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/

Now, from that code alone, **it doesn't seem like he's passing any handles to these "register" functions,** so take a look at the source, he has to pass their names within that class' static methods.